# String and list processing in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, swi-prolog

I am taking sentence as input, then convert it to lowercase. Create list of this sentence for each word, then iterate through this list and search for particular keyword.

I tried in different way but still could not achieve:

Convert into lowercase:

```
tolower([], []).
tolower([Upper|UpperTail], [Lower|LowerTail]) :-
    char_type(Lower, to_lower(Upper)),tolower(UpperTail, LowerTail).
```

issue is, it gives result in list format:

```
1 ?- tolower("Try This STRING", Lower).
Lower = [t, r, y, ' ', t, h, i, s, ' '|...].
```

Searching for string in sentence :

```
substring(Atom, Substring):-
    sub_atom(Atom, _, _, _, Substring).

1 ?- substring('... Where is that?', 'Where').
true .
```

but converting sentence into lowercase, converting into tockens and iterating over list is still not available. This is the simple code I want to convert into python.

```
def process(read):
    in_notin_result = (
        ('who',      [],       'person'),
        ('where',    ['what'], 'location'),
        ('why',      [],       'reason'),
        ('how many', [],       'count'),
        ('when',     ['what'], 'time'),
        ('how',      [],       'manner'),
    )
    words = read.split()
    for in_sent, notin_read, result in in_notin_result:
        if in_sent in words and all(disallowed not in read for disallowed in notin_read):
            return result
    return None

def process_link(post_script_link_list, read_str):
    read_str = read_str.lower()

    for item in ('how long', 'how much'):
        if item in read_str:
            return

    for linking in post_script_link_list:
        sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)', linking).group(1)

        if sub_link in ['Wq','Ws','Wi','Wd']:
            process_result = process(read_str)
            if process_result is not None:
                return process_result

        elif sub_link in ['Qd']:
            return 'Yes/No' if verify_yesno(post_script_link_list) else 'noresult'

    return 'noresult'
```

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has some idiomatic [NL processing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/nlp.html%27%29) capabilities, for instance

```
?- tokenize_atom('Try This STRING',L), maplist(downcase_atom,L,D).
L = ['Try', 'This', 'STRING'],
D = [try, this, string].
```

Regular expressions support (in plain Prolog) can be installed from [this pack](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=regex), but - my opinion - it's easier to code a DCG.
If you badly need regex, more efficient than the pack, there is the old [XPCE regex](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=pce_xref_gui:text_to_regex/2) interface...